# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) specified by user

Tags: django, django-users, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have extended `AbstractBaseUser` model to create a custom User model.

In my **accounts/models.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False, is_active=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have a password')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.is_staff = is_staff
        user.is_admin = is_admin
        user.is_active = is_active
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        return self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_active=True
        )

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        return self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True,
            is_active=True
        )


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        if self.first_name is not None:
            return self.get_full_name()

        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.last_name is not None:
            return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

        return self.get_short_name()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
```

and to use this `User` model for admin as well. I have added below code to 
**accounts/admin.py** as given in [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

```
from accounts.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
        fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
        the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
        password hash display field.
        """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
    ordering = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

But when I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**It gives error as**

```
File "/Users/anuj/code/PyCharm/notepad/src/accounts/admin.py", line 37, in <module>
    class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (is_staff, is_active) specified for User
```

removing `is_staff` and `is_active` from `UserChangeForm` works fine. I have even fields added to model.

Comment: Your `is_staff` and `is_active` fields are overwritten by your properties with the same name.

Comment: Are you sure you need to subclass `AbstractBaseUser`? You will need a lot less code if you subclass `AbstractUser`.

Comment: @Alasdair, I have to change `id` primary key field type from `int` to `uuid` and set `email` as `username` field. This is only what I have to do with this model. I'm confused between `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser` which one to use.

Comment: `AbstractUser` defines fields like `is_staff` that `AbstractBaseUser` does not. If you use `AbstractBaseUser` then you’ll have to write more code to get it to work with the Django admin.

Comment: can you please write an answer how to do all that I want using `AbstractUser`? Once again I only want to change `id` column to `UUID` from `int`. Rest is all fine

Comment: No, sorry, that's too much work, I can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a custom user model for authentication you must say so in your settings

In settings.py write:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/)